# access denied("java.net.NetPermission" "getProxySelector")

Tags: java, h2o, rapidminer

I am working on the extension development of rapidminer. I downloaded the template of the extension project from github and developed my own operator. After launching rapidminer, the extension was successfully installed.

[image]

**In the test code, I manually created the process and added operator. The operation was successful and the operator successfully completed the calculation.**

[image]

But when I dragged the module from the rapidminer software to accomplish the same thing, I reported this error:

[image]

This my operator :
[image]

[image]
[image]

And this is rapidminer' method to checkPermission:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RapidMiner has a security feature to prevent the unchecked execution of potentially risky extensions.To still execute your extension, you can check under the setting to give unsigned extensions (those that don't come from the RapidMiner marketplace) to be executed with additional rights.

[image]

For more detailed questions I also recommend to post at the [RapidMiner community](https://community.rapidminer.com/t5/Developer-Forum/bd-p/BARDDBoard) where a lot of experienced extensions developers can be found.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But When I checked this option, it shows "a large license is required to grant additional permissions to unsighed extensions. " What is a large license?  I used the academic plan to get the license. So if I want to check this option, I have to buy a paid license?

Comment: Or how can I make this extension which I developed a signed extension?

Comment: At the moment, you need a commercial license to use the "unsigned extension" option. You can also try to apply for a trial license during your development phase.

Comment: There is no chance that I can use a free license to do my development with the unsighed extension? But we are not decided to use RM or not, I want to run the program and extension more locally . So I think RM is not so much friendly to the developer.